# Data analytics on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, data-analysis

We are using Apache Cassandra to save data into. Except the spark what are the tools/technologies to perform the data analytics after reading data from cassandra. Spark is good but it needs a programmer(java/scala/python) to add/modify the future requirements which leads to high maintenance cost. What are the other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with Spark on top of Cassandra, many have accomplished good results with [Cassandra, Hive, and Hadoop](http://blog.markedup.com/2013/03/cassandra-real-time-analytics/).  Others have accomplished similar results using a mix of [Cassandra, Hive, and Solr](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkedUpAnalytics/real-time-analytics-with-cassandra-hive-and-solr).

Another decent set of slides and tutorial for running analysis of data via [Cassandra and Hadoop](http://strataconf.com/stratany2013/public/schedule/detail/30360).  You will find more in depth explanation of this via the PDF download on the provided page.

If you're interested in continuing to pursue Spark, you can evaluate [DataStax Enterprise](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-analytics), which took the complexity out of it and allows you to run Spark right on top of Cassandra.

To answer your question, you have a few industry proven options...  Primarily Hadoop and Hive.

Comment: is it possible to use hive/pig without using HDFS? I have data stored in the Cassandra and i want data analytics right on top if Cassandra